# Google AdWords ad request returning: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've had google ads on my website but they disappeared suddenly.
I've been trying to return it back by creating a new google ad, but nothing seems to fix the issue.
Here is the website link: http://www.getrefm.com/blog/
You'll see a white empty space below the "Subscribe" section in the sidebar; that's where the google ads should appear.
And here is the Javascript error that I get, maybe it will help:

```
GET http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4317973922365988&output=html&h=280&slotname=2909580283&w=336&lmt=1328235388&flash=11.1.102&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.getrefm.com%2Fblog%2F&dt=1328242589011&bpp=4&shv=r20120125&jsv=r20110914&correlator=1328242589167&frm=20&adk=3241743954&ga_vid=539225247.1328242589&ga_sid=1328242589&ga_hid=1931246443&ga_fc=0&u_tz=120&u_his=1&u_java=1&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1040&u_aw=1920&u_cd=32&u_nplug=33&u_nmime=125&dff=verdana&dfs=13&adx=1117&ady=695&biw=1903&bih=633&oid=3&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.getrefm.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2Fwidgets.php&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=300&xpc=lpwUPwRUgo&p=http%3A//www.getrefm.com 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: Look at the URL in your error message... it has nothing to do with Google Ads.  There is no programming question here and I think you need to contact Google.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you're talking about, it seems like I copied the wrong error message, not I just edited my question and added the google ads error I'm getting.

Comment: I don't get an error. I also don't see any ads on your website. When I extract your ad code into a local file and view it in a web browser, there is no ad. Finally, when I replace the values of google_ad_client and google_ad_slot with my own, an ad appears.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. @JohnPick your comment about swapping the ad client and slot IDs was interesting, however it didn't work in my case.  I do believe there is a valid question being asked here.  Karim were you able to resolve this?  I'm seeing the same `400 (Bad Request)` error but only intermitently.  Google searches haven't turned up anything yet.

Comment: It turned out that it was all about the PIN code that gets mailed to me. Everything is good now.